# MessageReceiver2topic/Subscriptions/mutationProcessor' is force detached

Tags: azure-servicebus-topics, azure-functions-runtime

We are having issues with an Import process and after investigation it looks like its related to issues with a Service Bus.

Exception #1

The link '678ed7a8-31d5-4236-8cc1-a316c3329943;42:47:48:source(address:topic/Subscriptions/mutationProcessor):MessageReceiver2topic/Subscriptions/mutationProcessor' is force detached. Code: RenewToken. Details: Unauthorized access. 'Listen' claim(s) are required to perform this operation. Resource: 'sb://asb.servicebus.windows.net/topic/subscriptions/mutationprocessor'.. TrackingId:b352c1a9858b497b869a58a7be09ae2a_G12, SystemTracker:gateway7, Timestamp:2020-07-27T15:18:02

Expectation:

1. What happens to messages that are sent when the subscription(s) is detached.
2. Work arounds/fixes

GitHub links for reference:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11619
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8884

The connection was inactive for more than the allowed 60000 milliseconds and is closed by container '1c7fe518-491a-47dd-aa5e-5ae96f0245df'.

Below is a MS documentation link which describes similar but not exact message.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-troubleshoot

Expectation:

1. Would this cause any issues in case messages were sent when the connection is inactive. If yes, please suggest a way to handle it.

GitHub links for reference:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/280